# XSLT Display only one row that matches id

Tags: xml, xslt, select

I am currently strugling transforming my XML to match my needs.
XML code is as follows:

```
<stk:stockPriceItem>
<stk:stockPrice>
<typ:id>11</typ:id>
<typ:ids>sleva 3%</typ:ids>
<typ:price>743.6</typ:price>
</stk:stockPrice>
<stk:stockPrice>
<typ:id>9</typ:id>
<typ:ids>V.I.P. 0%</typ:ids>
<typ:price>613.3</typ:price>
</stk:stockPrice>
<stk:stockPrice>
<typ:id>4</typ:id>
<typ:ids>Velko 5%</typ:ids>
<typ:price>552</typ:price>
</stk:stockPrice>
<stk:stockPrice>
<typ:id>12</typ:id>
<typ:ids>eshop</typ:ids>
<typ:price>651.6</typ:price>
</stk:stockPrice>
<stk:stockPrice>
<typ:id>5</typ:id>
<typ:ids>Malo 10%</typ:ids>
<typ:price>582.6</typ:price>
</stk:stockPrice>
<stk:stockPrice>
<typ:id>1</typ:id>
<typ:ids>Prodejní</typ:ids>
<typ:price>766.6</typ:price>
</stk:stockPrice>
</stk:stockPriceItem>
```

I need output, when my new transformed XML will display only typ:price for typ:id=12.

So as follows:

```
<stk:stockPrice>
 <typ:price>1222</typ:price>
</stk:stockPrice>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, as I could not find a solutions online and I am pretty newby in using XSLT.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Whenever you have namespaces, always include root tag. Please post fuller XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use predicate in pattern to obtain the target element such like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:stk="urn:stk" xmlns:typ="urn:typ"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="stk:stockPriceItem">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="stk:stockPrice[string(typ:id) eq '12']" priority="5">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="typ:price"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[The output]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stk:stockPrice xmlns:stk="urn:stk" xmlns:typ="urn:typ">
   <typ:price>651.6</typ:price>
</stk:stockPrice>
```

Note the namespace declaration is temporary because you didn't specified them in input XML file.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out resolution for my problem using this.

```
<xsl:value-of select="stk:stockPrice[typ:id=12]/typ:price"/>
```

Thank you for your help.